# Material-ui v0 Safari iOS dialog content scroll

Tags: material-ui

Safari mobile.
If i scroll sidebar, it is doing very quickly.  But if I try scroll Dialog content, it is doing very slow and sometimes scroll background instead..

I wrote video, where you can find that effect. 
https://yadi.sk/i/VXgqHfW83YbbN3

Does any solutions for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the Dialog content scroll normally on iOS, you have to add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to the CSS.
The background scrolling when you don't want it to is a bit of a harder problem, but you can find some more information here: [iOS - css/js - Overlay scroll but prevent body scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713970/ios-css-js-overlay-scroll-but-prevent-body-scroll)